# How do you set up an Ubuntu server that is "encrypted at rest"?

Tags: security, encryption

We're working on a project in which the customer needs the Ubuntu server on which a web app and database are running to be "encrypted at rest". What's the best way to implement this?

Comment: That's highly situational.  It seems to me like you're asking about an PCI compliance web-app.  The easiest way I've seen this done is mule-ing out the payment details to a payment gateway.  Then just handle user identity on the web-app

Comment: We have no payments system in the app. It's the application data itself that must be encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but I cant understand what you mean with "encrypted at rest"

if you want to encrypt parts of the system i would recomend lukscrypt and lvm.

http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-encrypted-partitions-over-lvm-with-luks

you will need to have installed LVM when you install the server
I would just but the database and the files which you need to keep encrypted on a logical volume in LVM and require manual opening the encrypted partition after each reboot